# Ensure Google service accounts

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

In Terraform I enable services like so:

```
resource "google_project_service" "apigateway" {
  service = "apigateway.googleapis.com"
}
```

Afterwards I ensure that I am referencing the service account of *apigateway* (`service-123@gcp-sa-apigateway.iam.gserviceaccount.com`) only after the resource was created.

Now it does happen sometimes that when using the email of sa, I get an error that the service account is not present:

> Error 400: Service account service-123@gcp-sa-apigateway.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not exist.

I double checked in API Explorer that the API is enabled!

This in turn does happen for *apigateway* the same way as for others (e.g. *cloudfunctions*).
So I am wondering how do I ensure that the service account is created?

Naively I assumed creating `google_project_service`s should do the trick but that seems not be true in every case. Documentation around Google service account is pretty sparse it seems :(

Comment: I am not sure - try a **depends_on**. I am not sure if the resource waits until a dependant service account is created.

Comment: Already using `depends_on`. It does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `apigateway` specifically, Google Support confirmed that undocumented behavior is the SA gets created lazily when creating first resource.

Comment: Please include a reference or the entire wording that Google supplied.

Answer (score 0):

As John Hanley remarks, you can create this [dependency in terraform](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/dependencies#manage-explicit-dependencies) with depends_on.

As you can see on the following comment, the service account will be created but the key will be assigned until the first sentence is done.

```
  resource "google_service_account" "service_account" {
  account_id   = "terraform-test"
  display_name = "Service Account"
}

resource "google_service_account_key" "mykey" {
  service_account_id = google_service_account.service_account.id
  public_key_type    = "TYPE_X509_PEM_FILE"

  depends_on = [google_service_account.service_account]
}
```

Also, if the service account is already created on the GCP platform only is executed the key statement.

It is important noticed that the account that you are using for this configuration needs to have the required IAM permission to [create an account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#permissions).

Comment: I am already utilizing `depends_on`. This question is specifically about implicit created service accounts!

Comment: @abergmeier - Your question does not show that. Update your question include enough details to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Note that apigateways and their google managed service account work different (currently). This is not documented.

Answer (score 0):

Found out about `google_project_service_identity`.

So since I saw this problem with *cloudfunctions* you could create a `google_project_service_identity.cloudfunctions` and hope for a detailed error message.

Sadly this is not available for all, e.g. *apigateway*.